# Prove: If the function $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, differentiable on $(a,b)$ and $f'(x) = 0$ on $(a,b)$, then f must be a constant function

Tags: analysis

Prove: If the function $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, differentiable on $(a,b)$ and $f'(x) = 0$ on $(a,b)$, then $f$ must be a constant function on $[a,b]$.

I need to select some $x_1$ and $x_2$ in $[a,b]$ such that $x_1$ is not equal to $x_2$ therefore by the mean value theorem.. This is where I am getting a bit confused how to apply MVT to this proof.. Hints/Tips appreciated. I may be over thinking things. Thanks.

Comment: Just a note: You should start with $x_1\in[a,b]$ *fixed*, and $x_2\in[a,b]$ arbitrary. Then show $f(x_2)=f(x_1)$.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{f(x_1) - f(x_2)}{x_1-x_2} & = f'(c) 
\text{ (for some }c\text{ between }x_1\text{ and }x_2\text{)} \\  \\  \\
& = 0
\end{align}
$$
Therefore $f(x_1)-f(x_2)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

So we have this:
f is differentiable on $(a,b)$, continuous on $[a,b]$, and $f'(x)=0, \forall x\in(a,b)$

We considered some arbitrary $x_1, x_2\in(a,b) \ni x_1 \neq x_2$

Then by MVT we have $f'(x)=\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2 - x_1}$.

$\Rightarrow$ $0=\frac{f(x_2) - f(x_1)}{x_2 - x_1}$

$\Rightarrow$ $0(x_2-x_1)=f(x_2)-f(x_1)$

$\Rightarrow$ $0=f(x_2)-f(x_1)$

$\Rightarrow$ $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$

Thus $\forall x\in (a,b) f(x)=c \in\mathbb{R}$, as desired.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your answer adds nothing new to the already existing answers.