# Function with the same derivative are equal up to a constant 

Tags: real-analysis, functions

If functions $f$ and $g$ are continuous on $[a,b]$ differentiable on $(a,b)$, and $f'(x) = g'(x)$ on $(a,b)$, then there exists a real number $K$ such that $f(x) = g(x) + K$ for all $x\in [a,b]$.

Comment: Hint: Let $p(x)=f(x)-g(x)$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Set $h=f-g$. Show that $h$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and that  $h'$ is identically zero on $(a,b)$. Then use the result of a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130961/prove-if-the-function-f-is-continuous-on-a-b-differentiable-on-a-b-a) of yours.